# I send some json array data in postman but it seems error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

`And my postman data

===============================

```
Content-Type:application/json
{
    "appointment_id": "5d3ab1a4590ad324b2abdb76",
    "remarks" : "Next checkup after one month",
    "diagnosis":[
        {
            "diagnosis_description": "Fiver"
        }
    ],
    "investigation":[
        {
            "test_name" : "Blood",
            "test_description" : "Dengu"
        },
        {
            "test_name" : "Blood",
            "test_description" : "HIV"
        }
    ],
    "medicine":[
        {
            "medicine_name":"Paracetamol",
            "medicine_dosage":"650",
            "medicine_power":"AM"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the JSON data and I just want to post it as a raw data but have some error in node.js end

> TypeError: This library (validator.js) validates strings only

technology used: Express.js and mongoose

PrescriptionModel

```
let prescriptionSchema = new Schema({

    appointment_id: {
        required: [true, 'Appointment id is required'],
        type :Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Appointments'
    },
    remarks: {
        type: String,
    },
    diagnosis: [{ 
        diagnosis_description: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }],
    investigation: [{ 
        test_name: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        test_description: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }],
    medicine: [{ 
        medicine_name: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        medicine_dosage: {
            type: String,
        }, 
        medicine_power: {
            type: String,
        }, 
    }]

}, 

{timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
}});
```

> "TypeError: This library (validator.js) validates strings only"

Comment: Can you show how you handle the data at your endpoint? My guess is you are trying to validate a JSON object and not cast it to string first

Comment: actually i am sending "Content-Type:application/json" data via postman ,please check the above data